# Sorting adapter on particular array

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have a collection of object assigned to an adapter set to a listview. I know how to sort an adapter value when it contains single object. My question is how do I sort the collection only on the data datatype. Below is my collection

```
you = new MyVideoAdapter(getActivity(),vDancers,video, vName, vDanceStyle, vOwner, dCountry, vPic, vCreated, fullname,
                        vLikes,vComments, vViews,vRepost, objectID, nLikes, nComments, nRepost, vUserID, postType);
                //you.comp
                listView.setAdapter(you);
```

I  want to sort this adapter (you) by the vCreated which is an array of dates. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a solution, this is how I went about it (I don't know if its the best solution but it does work for my case). 
1. Instead of populating the adapter with the individual arrays, I created an ArrayList and populated it with my arrays.I sorted it using compareTo().

```
public class Items implements Comparable<Items>{

private final Number vLikes; private final Number vComments; private final Number vRepost; private final Number vViews;
private  final Date vCreated;

public Items(Number vLikes, Number vComments, Number vViews, Number vRepost, Date created) {
    this.vCreated = vCreated;
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.vLikes = vLikes;
    this.vComments = vComments;
    this.vViews = vViews;
    this.vRepost = vRepost;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Items o) {
    if (getvCreated() == null || o.getvCreated() == null)
        return 0;
    return o.getvCreated().compareTo(getvCreated());
}

public Number getvLikes() {
    return vLikes;
}

public Number getvComments() {
    return vComments;
}

public Number getvViews() {
    return vViews;
}

public Number getvRepost() {
    return vRepost;
}
public Date getvCreated() {
    return vCreated;
}
}
```

2. I then sort the arraylist using the date column and using Collections to apply the sorting.

```
List<Items> myList = new ArrayList<Items>();
Items item = new Items(a,b,c,d);//a, b, are my variables
myList.add(item);
```

3. I populated my adapter with the sorted arraylist.

```
Collections.sort(myList);
you = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), myList);
```

I hope this helps.